# Brickschema Information

Tags: schema, iot, gateway

I am working on an IoT gateway like raspberry pi. So I want to use **Brickschema** for data modelling and data normalisation of sensors data. I had gone through a paper [link](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10111028) and find some theory about brickschema. There I didn't find the implementation thing. Could you tell me how can I start working with Brickschema using python libraries and what I need to integrate with brick to model the sensor data..? Please share me some example to implement Brickschema for my IoT gateway.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. Its quite easy: Load the brick as a graph. Add the relations you want (eg. by direcktly adding triples to the graph or SPARQL Insert). Use the graph to maintain / plan your IoT house: https://brickschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orm.html